# How can I debug this report with the following errors? See details

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I get the following error messages in this order when I attempt to run the report:

1. The specified TargetServerURL is not valid. Specify a valid URL for a report server in the deployment settings.
2. The project cannot be debugged because no starting report is specified.
   In the Project Menu, select Properties and enter a value for StartItem.

The output from Build looks like this:

```
------ Build started: Project: Accounts Billed Per User, Configuration: Debug ------
Skipping 'LVP.rds'. Item is up to date.
Skipping 'Accounts Billed Per User.rdl'. Item is up to date.
Skipping 'Energy Customers With CSP Liscenses.rsd'. Item is up to date.
Skipping 'Customers.rsd'. Item is up to date.
Build complete -- 0 errors, 0 warnings
========== Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

The screenshot of my project looks like this:
[image]

See the comment section below for the latest development in this issue.

Thank you for checking out my question.

Comment: What do your deployment settings look like?

Comment: I did not know that this existed because I've never deployed a report from Visual Studio before. However, I looked into it and found that the report was configured to deploy. I unchecked this box and now the report is only configured to build. Unfortunately, now I have a different error message:
The project cannot be debugged because no starting report is specified.
In the Project Menu, select Properties and enter a value for StartItem.

Comment: I am able to run the report but not the project.

Comment: Just right click on your project and select properties. In general properties under debug section provide your report name for start item.

Comment: Thanks @CuriousKid !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tab Alleman and CuriousKid led me to solve my problems. Thank you so much for the help!

1. Right clicked the **Solution**
2. Went to **Configuration Manager...**

[image]

3. Unchecked **Deploy** for the project

[image]

4. Right clicked the **Project**
5. Went to **Properties**

[image]

6. Provided the report for the **Debug** section's **StartItem**

[image]

Now the report runs immediately when I debug the solution.